# Generating PDFs from Angular Component using jsPDF and html2canvas - Blank Output Issue

Tags: angular

I'm currently working on an Angular project where I need to generate PDFs from a component's content. I'm using `jsPDF` and `html2canvas` for this task, but I'm facing an issue where the generated PDFs are coming out blank. I would really appreciate some guidance or suggestions on what might be going wrong.

Here's a brief overview of what I'm trying to achieve:

- I have a component named `VerCertificadoToma`, which displays the details of a financial operation as a certificate.
- I'm trying to generate a PDF for each selected operation in a grid, and then combine these PDFs into a single file.

The relevant part of my `VerCertificadoToma` component looks like this:

```js
import { CertificadoServiceService } from 'src/app/services/CertificadoService.service';
import {Component, Input} from "@angular/core";
import {ArchivosResponse} from "../../interfaces/Archivos/ArchivosResponse.interface";
import {DynamicDialogConfig} from "primeng/dynamicdialog";
import {OperacionesService} from "../../services/operaciones.service";
import {DepositosAplazoInterface} from "../../interfaces/Depositos/DepositosAplazo.interface";
import {CondicionesComercialesInterface} from "../../interfaces/CondicionesComerciales.interface";
import {FechasFormat, FORMATO_FECHA, TIPO_CONSULTA} from "../../shared/Constantes";


@Component({
  template: `
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
    <button pButton pRipple type="button" icon="pi pi-arrow-down"
            (click)="openPDF()"
            class="p-button-rounded p-button-outlined"></button>
    <div id="htmlData">
    <h1 class="colorBCH">CERTIFICADO DE DEPOSITO A PLAZO {{ (deposito.codMoneda=='998' || deposito.codMoneda=='999')? "REAJUSTABLE EN UF":"" }}</h1>
    <hr size="5">
    <table>
      <tr align="top">
        <td>
          <table>
            <tr><td class="colorSubBCH"><strong>1.-ANTECEDENTES DEL CLIENTE</strong></td></tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table>
                  <tr>
                    <td><strong>Nombre Titular:</strong>MINISTERIO PUBLICO</td><td>Rut: 61.935.400-1</td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
            </tr>
            <tr><td class="colorSubBCH"><strong>2.-ANTECEDENTES DE LA OPERACION</strong></td></tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table width="100%">
                  <tr>
                    <td><strong>N° Operación:</strong></td>
                    <td>{{ deposito.numOperacion}}</td>
                    <td><strong>Fec.Emision:</strong></td>
                    <td>{{ convertir(deposito.fechaEmision,formatoFecha)}}</td>
                    <td><strong>Mto Dep. {{ (deposito.codMoneda=='998' || deposito.codMoneda=='999')?"en($):":"" }}</strong></td>
                    <td *ngIf="deposito.codMoneda=='998' || deposito.codMoneda=='999' " style="text-align: right">{{ deposito.montoPeso | currency:'CLP':''}}</td>
                    <td *ngIf="deposito.codMoneda=='13'" style="text-align: right">{{ deposito.montoOrigen | currency:'USD':''}}</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><strong>Plazo:</strong></td>
                    <td>{{ deposito.plazo}}</td>
                    <td><strong>Fec.Vencimiento:</strong></td>
                    <td>{{ convertir(deposito.fechaVencimiento,formatoFecha)}}</td>
                    <td><strong>Valor futuro a pagar:</strong></td><td></td></tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><strong>Tasa:</strong></td>
                    <td>{{ deposito.tasaBase  | number:'1.4-4' }}</td>
                    <td><strong>Renovable:</strong></td><td>SI</td><td></td><td></td></tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><strong>Monto inversión:</strong></td>
                    <td *ngIf="deposito.codMoneda=='998' || deposito.codMoneda=='999' " >{{ deposito.montoPeso | currency:'CLP':''}}</td>
                    <td *ngIf="deposito.codMoneda=='13'" >{{ deposito.montoOrigen | currency:'USD':''}}</td>
                    <td><strong>Endoso:</strong></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
                </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td class="colorSubBCH"><strong>3.-RECAUDACION</strong></td></tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table width="100%">
                  <tr>
                    <td><strong>Cuenta origen:</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Monto:</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Fiscalía regional:</strong></td>
                    <td><strong>Fiscalía local:</strong></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>{{deposito.numCuentaCorriente }}</td>
                    <td *ngIf="deposito.codMoneda=='998' || deposito.codMoneda=='999' " >{{ deposito.montoPeso | currency:'CLP':''}}</td>
                    <td *ngIf="deposito.codMoneda=='13'" >{{ deposito.montoOrigen | currency:'USD':''}}</td>
                    <td>{{deposito.fiscaliaRegionalTxt}}</td>
                    <td>{{deposito.fiscaliaZonalTxt}}</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><strong>RUC:</strong>{{ deposito.ruc }}</td>
                    <td><strong>RUE:</strong>{{ deposito.rue }}</td><td></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td class="colorSubBCH"><strong>4.- AUTORIZADORES</strong></td></tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table style="width:100%">
                  <tr>
                    <td><strong>Autorizador 1:</strong></td><td>{{deposito.autorizador1 | uppercase}}</td>
                    <td><strong>Autorizador 2:</strong></td><td>{{deposito.autorizador2 | uppercase}}</td>
                    <td><img src="{{ 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + deposito.logo }}"></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><hr></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
               <div class="card" *ngFor="let item of condiciones">
                 <div class="card-header"><strong>{{ item.titulo  }}</strong></div>
                 <div class="p-card-body">{{ item.contenido  }}</div>
               </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </html>
    `,
  styles: [' .colorBCH { color:#e1a154 }' +
  '.colorSubBCH { color:#ffa521}'
  ]

})
export class VerCertificadoToma {
  @Input() numOperacion:any;
  archivos: ArchivosResponse[] = [];
  public UrlOrgin= window.location.origin;
  idRendicion = "";
  public formatoFecha = FORMATO_FECHA.DDMMYYYY;
  public deposito!: DepositosAplazoInterface;
  public condiciones!:CondicionesComercialesInterface[];
  constructor(private operacionesService: OperacionesService,
              public config: DynamicDialogConfig,
              private CertificadoServiceService: CertificadoServiceService) {
    this.numOperacion = config.data.numOperacion;

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.operacionesService.getOperacionByNumOperacion(this.numOperacion,TIPO_CONSULTA.RENDICIONES)
      .subscribe({
         next: (data:any)=>{
           this.deposito = data;
           this.operacionesService.getCondicionesComerciales(this.numOperacion)
             .subscribe({
               next: (condiciones:any)=>{
                 this.condiciones  = condiciones;
               }
             });

        },
        error: (err:any)=>{
           console.log(err);
         }
      });
  }



  convertir(fechaReturn: string, formato: number): string {
    let  laFecha:FechasFormat = new  FechasFormat();
    if( formato==FORMATO_FECHA.DDMMYYYY) {
        fechaReturn  = laFecha.convertir(fechaReturn,FORMATO_FECHA.DDMMYYYY);
    }
    return fechaReturn;
  }

  public openPDF(): void {
    // Espera a que el contenido HTML esté completamente cargado y renderizado
    new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)).then(() => {
      // Luego genera y descarga el PDF
      this.CertificadoServiceService.generatePDF('htmlData').then((blob) => {
        this.CertificadoServiceService.saveBlobAsPDF(blob, 'toma-deposito.pdf');
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error generando el PDF:', error);
      });
    });
  }


}
```

In the service CertificadoServiceService, I have methods to generate PDFs from the DOM elements and combine them:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
import { PDFDocument } from 'pdf-lib';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CertificadoServiceService {

  public async generatePDF(id: string): Promise<Blob> {
    if (!id) {
      throw new Error('ID no proporcionado para generar PDF');
    }
    const DATA = document.getElementById(id);
    if (!DATA) throw new Error(`Elemento con ID ${id} no encontrado`);

    const canvas = await html2canvas(DATA);
    const fileWidth = 208;
    const fileHeight = (canvas.height * fileWidth) / canvas.width;
    const FILEURI = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    const PDF = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
    const position = 0;
    PDF.addImage(FILEURI, 'PNG', 0, position, fileWidth, fileHeight);

    return PDF.output('blob');
  }

  async combinePDFBlobs(pdfBlobs: Blob[]): Promise<Blob> {
    const mergedPdf = await PDFDocument.create();

    for (const pdfBlob of pdfBlobs) {
      const pdfBytes = await pdfBlob.arrayBuffer();
      const pdf = await PDFDocument.load(pdfBytes);
      const copiedPages = await mergedPdf.copyPages(pdf, pdf.getPageIndices());
      copiedPages.forEach((page: any) => {
        mergedPdf.addPage(page);
      });
    }

    const mergedPdfBytes = await mergedPdf.save();
    return new Blob([mergedPdfBytes], { type: 'application/pdf' });
  }


  saveBlobAsPDF(blob: Blob, filename: string): void {
    const downloadURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = downloadURL;
    link.download = filename;
    document.body.appendChild(link); // Necesario para Firefox
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link); // Limpiar el DOM
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadURL); // Limpiar la URL
  }


  public async descargarCertificadosCombinados(operacionesSeleccionadas: any[]): Promise<void> {
    // Asegúrate de que estás utilizando la propiedad 'id' que existe en tus objetos de operación
    console.log('Operaciones seleccionadas:', operacionesSeleccionadas);
    const idsDeElementos = operacionesSeleccionadas.map(op => op.id ? op.id.toString() : null).filter(id => id !== null);

    try {
      // Generar PDFs individuales de cada elemento basado en el 'id' de la operación
      const pdfBlobs = await Promise.all(idsDeElementos.map(id => this.generatePDF(id)));

      // Combinar los PDFs en un solo Blob
      const combinedPdfBlob = await this.combinePDFBlobs(pdfBlobs);

      // Descargar el PDF combinado
      this.saveBlobAsPDF(combinedPdfBlob, 'certificados_combinados.pdf');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error al generar o combinar los PDFs:', error);
      // Aquí deberías manejar el error, como mostrar un mensaje de error al usuario
    }
  }


}
```

```
onDescargarPDFsSeleccionados() {
// Suponiendo que 'operacionesSeleccionadas' contiene las operaciones seleccionadas
// y cada operación tiene una propiedad 'id' que corresponde al elemento del DOM
const idsDeElementos = this.operacionesSeleccionadas.map((op: { id: { toString: () => any; }; }) => op.id ? op.id.toString() : null);
setTimeout(() => {
  this.certificadoService.descargarCertificadosCombinados(idsDeElementos);
}, 1000);
```

}

The issue arises when I try to generate PDFs from selected operations. The PDFs are created, but they are blank. I suspect the problem might be related to how html2canvas is capturing the content, or perhaps an issue with the asynchronous data loading and rendering in Angular.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have suggestions on what might be causing this problem? Any advice on how to debug this effectively would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!